# How get a date (value) from a DatePicker and assign it to property an object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, datepicker

I'm using the `react-datepicker` library. How to extract a value from the `DatePicker` component and assign it to the`date` property in the `Pick` object. Downloading data from the input was simple. How to do it with a data picker?

```
class Form extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      startDate: new Date()
    }
  }

  create(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    const pick = {
      date: this.date.value, /
      color: this.color.value,
     description: this.description.value
    }

   this.form.reset();
  }

  handleChange = (date) => {
    this.setState({
      startDate: date
    });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <form ref={(input) => this.form= input} onSubmit={(e) => 
          this.create(e)}>
      <div>
          {/*<input ref={(input) => this.date = input} type="text" 
          />*/}
       <DatePicker
        dateFormat="yyyy/MM/dd"
        selected={this.state.startDate}
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
      />
      <input ref={(input) => this.time = input} type="text" />
    </div>

       <textarea ref={(input) => this.description = input} 
     placeholder="" ></textarea>

       <div >
         <button >Cancel</button>
         <button type="submit">Save</button>
       </div>
     </form>
    )
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the rest of your code functions as expected, when the form is submitted it will be in your state, so get it from there:

```
const pick = {
      date: this.state.startDate, 
      color: this.color.value,
     description: this.description.value
    }
```

Comment: I tried in this way. But I have error: `Uncaught Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: Wed Jun 05 2019 13:48:03 GMT+0200 (czas środkowoeuropejski letni)). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.`

Comment: Was that error caused by this change or did it exist before? Have you missed some code? Where is pick used?

Comment: When I changed. now

Comment: can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
handleChange = (e) => {
   this.setState( {[e.target.name]: e.target.value} )
}
```

you'll need to make sure that the name on the datePicker forms match the name in your state. So if your state is

```
this.state = {
   date: new Date();
}
```

Then the input on that field needs to be date as well.

```
 <input
                    name="date"
                    id="date"
                    type="date"
                    defaultValue="2017-05-24"
                    onChange={handleInputChange}
                    value={inputs.date}
                />
```

The method I posted allows you to reuse that for any form component. Just make sure you are matching the form input name and the state you are using.